# Kubuntu Graphical Desktop Not Displaying $HOME/Desktop Files

Tags: kubuntu

I'll make this as short as possible. I will refer to the "Desktop" to mean the area I see on the screen when no programs are open.

Today I installed Kubuntu 15.10. When I save files to Home/Desktop directory, they do not appear on the Desktop. Is there a way to change what I see on the Desktop to see the files that are in Home/Desktop?

In terminal, I navigated to $HOME/Desktop and the files I expected to see on my Desktop appear in that folder.
In the ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file, the first line is XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDE doesn't show files on the desktop in the usual way. It has this weird feature where you add folders to be displayed in resizable and draggable boxes. They're essentially widgets that show files.

To add a folder, open the Widget Options (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) and select the Folder widget. You can then configure it to show whichever folder you want.

Alternatively, right click on the desktop and choose the `Folder View` option. Make sure the desktop is "unlocked" (configurable).

Comment: Alt-D, A brings up the Widgets options. Within the widgets, you can select a folder to place on the desktop. Then you can configure the widget-folder to show files from the desired folder. I am new to Ubuntu, but was under the impression that it could be configured in many different ways. If this is the best option, and I do not hear a better solution, I will mark it as answered, but I'd really like to link to the $HOME/Desktop folder on the Desktop without having to use the widgets.

Comment: The problem is there's no framework to show files directly on the desktop.

Comment: Oh wait, there may be something. Is there a `configure desktop` option, either under the Widgets Menu (top right) or in the right-click menu of the desktop?

Comment: I would have sworn I had tried that Folder View option. Just now right-clicked the desktop, changed to Folder View, and now see the files I was expecting. Thanks!